# Get the invoice and access the hosted_invoice_url

Tags: stripe

**Cómo estás,**

Estoy tratando de recuperar una factura por medio del ID de factura, luego devuelve el objeto de factura para luego acceder a **"hospedado_invoice_url"** y mostrarlo por consola.

El propósito final es conseguir la **"URL_de_factura alojada"** mediante el ID de la factura, así lo he hecho pero no funciona

Otro segundo problema es que tengo que ejecutar app.js donde tengo los datos que se muestran en la imagen. Me gustaría publicarlo en mi página para pasar el ID de factura a través de una entrada y devolver la **"hospedada_invoice_url"**.

```
const Stripe = require('stripe')
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_51HDh.....')

stripe.invoices.retrieve(
    'in_1HE0TGG....',
    function (err, lines) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(lines)
        var myObj, x
        myObj = data
        x = myObj["hosted_invoice_url"]
        console.log(x)
    }
)
```

---

**¡Gracias por contestar a mi pregunta!**

He probado hacerlo de esta forma, la factura esta finalizada solo me faltaría servirlo a mi web.

El valor que representa el ID de la factura lo pasaré por un input, después debería retornar el hosted_invoice_url en pantalla.

- ¿Qué debo hacer para agregarlo como una función y no como un script?

```
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_....');

stripe.invoices.retrieve(
    'in_1HE0....',
    function (err, lines) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("[hosted_invoice_url] Capture Error!");
            return;
        }
        console.log("customer id =>", lines.hosted_invoice_url);
    }
);
```

Comment: agregué un ejemplo que te puede servir.

Answer (score 0):

El campo de `hosted_invoice_url` tendrá una URL válida sólo cuando el invoice está guardado. Te recomiendo que selecciones un Cliente, y le agregues una Factura. Con eso ya debieras poder acceder al URL.

Esto está detallado acá: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-hosted_invoice_url

Una vez obtenida la URL, puedes utilizar un poco de JavaScript para, por ejemplo, mostrar un botón:

```js
// Esto viene como parte del response body
const stripeInvoiceResponse = {
  "id": "in_123",
  "object": "invoice",
  "hosted_invoice_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_123/invst_123",
  "invoice_pdf": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_123/invst_123/pdf"
};

// Aquí puedes usar jQuery o cualquier otra herramienta de manipulación
// del DOM (e.g. React, etc)
document.getElementById("open-invoice").href = stripeInvoiceResponse.hosted_invoice_url;
```

```html
<a target="_blank" id="open-invoice">Abrir Factura</a>
```

En tu caso, el JavaScript podría verse como:

```
stripe.invoices.retrieve(
    'in_1HE0....',
    function (err, lines) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("[hosted_invoice_url] Capture Error!");
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("open-invoice").href = lines.hosted_invoice_url;
    }
);
```